# How can I tell if a Hibernate 4 entity is a proxy or the actual entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4, with lazy loading enabled. I have a basic entity that contains references to other objects. Below is a simple example:

```
    @Entity
    public class Employee{
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public Employee boss;
        //more code follows
    }
```

When I load the Employee entity from the database the boss object is represented by a Hibernate proxy object, due to lazy loading.  Later I need to access the boss property, which may or may not be in the same session it was loaded in. If I try to use the boss object and it hasn't been loaded and I am in a different seesion I will get the following error:

```
Cause: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

**How can I tell if the Employee entity the boss property is returning is a proxy or the actual entity?**

I really want an answer so I can do something like the following code:

```
    public Strin getBossName(Employee emp){
        Employee boss;
        if(isProxy(emp){
            boss = getBossFromDatabase(emp);
        }else{
            boss = emp.getBoss();
        }enter code here
        return boss.getName();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate provides such a facility in the [`Hibernate`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html) class:

```
Hibernate.isInitialized(emp)
```